# Show encoded html in WebView

Tags: android, html, json, webview, html-encode

I want to use WebView to show my script using:

```
webView.loadData(script, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

The script is sent by JSON and because of  the sending html:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bf_container{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.bf_item{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.bf_item img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bf_container">
        <div class="bf_item"> 
            <a href="#">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" onClick="Android.onAdClicked('app_url')">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bf_item"> 
            <a href="#">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bf_item"> 
            <a href="#">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="bf_item"> 
            <a href="#">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="bf_item"> 
            <a href="#">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="bf_item"> 
            <a href="#">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

has to be encoded to:

```
&lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;style&gt; html, body{ margin: 0; padding:0; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; } .bf_container{ width:100%; height: 100%; } .bf_item{ box-sizing: border-box; width: 33%; float:left; padding: 5px 10px; } .bf_item img{ max-width: 100%; } &lt;/style&gt; &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bf_container&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bf_item&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Title&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;http://placehold.it/350x150&quot; onClick=&quot;Android.onAdClicked('app_url')&quot;&gt; &lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bf_item&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Title&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;http://placehold.it/350x150&quot;&gt; &lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bf_item&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Title&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;http://placehold.it/350x150&quot;&gt; &lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bf_item&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Title&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;http://placehold.it/350x150&quot;&gt; &lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bf_item&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Title&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;http://placehold.it/350x150&quot;&gt; &lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;bf_item&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt; &lt;h3&gt;Title&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;http://placehold.it/350x150&quot;&gt; &lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;
```

What is the way to show such HTML in WebView properly ? Because so far it does not process the script but just shows script text.